# Why are my totals not happening in this little calculator?

Tags: c#, winforms

Starting with this simple little c# windows form tip calculator.  I made a VB version years ago which worked great and I ported to my Palm Treo and was handy back before apps were a thing in the mobile world.

So, for this Tip Calc, I have a basic windows form with 3 textbox fields: `Bill amount`, `Tip amount (%)` and `number of people`.

I have two labels: `label 1` to display tip total, `label 2` display grand total after dividing among party, etc.

I have been banging my head on getting the tip total label to populate during my free time the past 4 days and I just cant get past this hurdle.

I have a `calculate` button that, when clicked, will create variables, convert textbox data to decimal, (field validation to come later), add bill amount plus tip divided by total in party.

I ran debug on it and I can see the 'tree' variable populate with the desired total, but for whatever reason, `label7` will not populate with that total.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal check = Convert.ToDecimal(Check.Text);
        decimal tip = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
        decimal ppl = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);
        decimal tree = Convert.ToDecimal(tip * check);
        //    tree = Convert.ToDecimal(tip * check);
        if (Decimal.TryParse(label7.Text, out tree))
            MessageBox.Show(tree.ToString());
        //    else
        //       MessageBox.Show(Ex);
        //tree = Decimal.Parse(label7.Text);
        //try { tree = Decimal.Parse(label7.Text); }
        // catch (Exception ex) { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("There is some sort of error!"); }
        //label7.Visible = true;
        label8.Text = check + label7.Text;
        label8.Visible = true;
    }

    private void Check_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char check = e.KeyChar;

    }
}
```

**Update:** My formatting was awful indeed.  (Thanks Matti Virkkunen). I have since cleaned up.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal billamt = Convert.ToDecimal(check.Text);
    decimal tipamt = Convert.ToDecimal(tipAmt.Text);
    decimal people = Convert.ToDecimal(numPpl.Text);
    decimal calcttl = Convert.ToDecimal(tipamt * billamt);
    billWithTipLbl.Text = calcttl;
    billWithTipLbl.Visible = true;
    resultLabel.Text = billamt + billWithTipLbl.Text;
    resultLabel.Visible = true;
}
```

I should clarify.  My original issue was "cannot convert type decimal to string" error when I did assign billWithTipLbl.Text with the tree variable. 
Label7 has been replaced with billWithTipLbl.  I did have a BillWithTipLbl.Text=calcttl; (was label7.Text=tree;) defined once before, but kept getting "cannot convert type decimal to string".
What I misunderstood Decimal.TryParse() to be the way to convert properly so calcttl (was tree) could get shoved into the label text.

label8.Text(now resultLabel.Text) at the time seemed to have no problem taking decimal, I didn't understand why label7.Text(now billWithTipLbl.Text) was having a hard time with the decimal to string thing.

Comment: You never try to assign a value to `label7`...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your code that would put any text in `label7`.

In fact this line is doing the exact opposite of that by trying to read a number out of `label7` and put it into your `tree` variable:

```
if (Decimal.TryParse(label7.Text, out tree))
```

As you've already figured out with `label8`, to put anything into your label you will need to do something along the lines of `label7.Text = ...;`.

Also your naming is terrible. Why not rename your textboxes and labels into something meaningful, e.g. `resultLabel` instead of `label7`?

Comment: Thanks!  my naming was bad.  Result of trying this/that/and the other to get working. I've since cleaned up and updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand a bit upon the previous answer. You're misusing Decimal.TryParse().
All TryParse methods attempt to convert a given string to a given type. In this case, string to the value type Decimal. The method returns a true if the conversion was successful. The signature contains an out variable that accepts the converted value.

Here's an example using your form:

```
decimal check, tip, ppl;

if (Decimal.TryParse(Check.Text, out check) &&
    Decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out tip) &&
    Decimal.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out ppl)
    )
{
    decimal tree = tip * check;
    label7.Text = tree.ToString();
    label8.Text = check + label7.Text; // ??? What is this supposed to show?
    label8.Visible = true;
}
```

This accomplishes two things at once. It converts each of the text values to decimals and reports if each conversion succeeds (returns true), then performs the desired actions to the form labels.

The use of Decimal.TryParse() over Decimal.Parse() or Convert.ToDecimal() avoids certain exceptions. Alternatively, parse or conversion exceptions can be caught when thrown. TryParse() is often a cleaner and more efficient solution and should be used whenever user input can potentially contain values that do not translate to the desired type.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  The core of the problem was when I did label7.Text = tree;  Kept getting "cannot implicitly convert dec to string".  I couldn't figure it out with label8.Text not giving me the same error.
I now see the tree.ToString(); was needed for label7.Text.  I've also updated label8.Text=check+label7.Text to be check + tree.ToString(); and it seems I'm getting what I've been aiming for! Also, thank you for the clarification and demo on the Decimal.TryParse().  Helps me understand for sure.